# Where is the login screen wallpaper located?

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, desktop-background

I want to know this because I like the picture used and I'd like to use it elsewhere.  Where is the LightDM login screen wallpaper located in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 10):

It's stored at:

```
/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Wojciech Zylinski's answer, if you want to find the location of a custom wallpaper you've set, you can find it between the `<filename></filename>` tags in `~/.config/gnome-control-center/backgrounds/last-edited.xml` of your home folder.

Comment: For Xubuntu it's /home/xubuntu-matt/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the login graphic with ubuntu-tweak "Login Settings". There's a handy button that sets the background to whatever desktop wallpaper is in use. You can also change the login screen logo there as well. You can get a copy  at http://www.ubuntu-tweak.com.

Comment: Actually, he didn't want to change the wallpaper. He probably wanted the location of the wallpaper so that he can use it for other purposes...