# How can I get a image of the default login wallpaper?

Tags: desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the login screen wallpaper located?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97010/where-is-the-login-screen-wallpaper-located)

Where can I find the folder where the login screen background/wallpaper so that I can copy it to my **Pictures** folder? Or even better a Terminal command. I'm using **Bash**.

Answer (score 3):

The default is located at `/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png`

For the terminal command:

```
cp /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png ~/Pictures
```

Comment: The login wallpaper/background is a little different than the **warty-final-ubuntu.png**. Where can I find that file?

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you using ? K/L/Xubuntu ? Post a link or screenshot of the background you are looking for.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 11.10. I installed Ubuntu through Wubi, if that helps.

Comment: Should be the file we gave you and if not we need a picture of what you are looking for. Alternately , open nautilus and navigate to /usr/share/backgrounds and browse for yourself.